# Displaying a Grid in Python With Different Values Based on User Inputs

Tags: python

I'm working through a battleship game project in Python.  I'm stuck on displaying the placed ships on the grid. Here is my function that displays an updated board based on the user's inputted coordinates--which are in the form of letter, number like A10. The user grid is a 10x10 box.  The empty board is printed with a "O" and vertical ships are supposed to be printed with a | character, while horizontal printed with a --.   Here is my function to update the board after all the coordinates have been set.

```
def print_updated_board(coords, direction):
    board = []
    for row in range(10):
        board_row = []
        updated = []
        for c in range(ord('a'), ord('a') + BOARD_SIZE):
            t = chr(c) + str(row)
            board_row.append(t)
        if direction == 'v':
            for coord in coords:
                for w in board_row:
                    if coord == w:
                        updated.append(VERTICAL_SHIP)
                    else:
                        updated.append(EMPTY)
        board.append(updated)
    print_board_heading()
    row_num = 1
    for row in board:
        print(str(row_num).rjust(2) + " " + (" ".join(row)))
        row_num += 1
```

the coords have been created based on size of ships, so example battleship with size of four, placed at a1 vertically, would have coordinates (a1, a2, a3, a4).  I'm just trying to print in this instance a | on those coordinates leaving the empty coordinates as O.

My code now is off--the grid appears to be erroneously printing 50 lines (instead of 10).

Any guidance on where to take this is appreciated.  Thanks

EDIT****************Realized i was double looping and changed code to this. Not working perfectly yet (it's off by one location) but working on it.

```
def print_updated_board(coords, direction):
    board = []
    for row in range(10):
        board_row = []
        updated = []
        for c in range(ord('a'), ord('a') + BOARD_SIZE):
            t = chr(c) + str(row)
            board_row.append(t)
        if direction == 'v':
            for b in board_row:
                if b in coords:
                    updated.append(VERTICAL_SHIP)
                else:
                    updated.append(EMPTY)
            board.append(updated)
    print_board_heading()
    row_num = 1
    for row in board:
        print(str(row_num).rjust(2) + " " + (" ".join(row)))
        row_num += 1
```

Comment: OK i sort of determined my problem-- i was double looping--once over the board and another over the coordinates for each ship.  Changed above code to reflect--my one issue is that the ship is printing one variable off the mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are these nested loops:

```
for coord in coords:
    for w in board_row:
        updated.append(...)
```

These cause the board to grow wider for each coordinate in the list.

---

The best solution is to throw all this code out the window, because there's a far easier way to do this:

```
def print_updated_board(coords, direction):
    # create an empty board
    board = [['O']*BOARD_SIZE for _ in range(BOARD_SIZE)]
    # at each coordinate, draw a ship
    for coord in coords:
        # convert string like "a1" to x,y coordinates
        y= ord(coord[0])-ord('a')
        x= int(coord[1:])-1
        # update the board at this position
        board[x][y]= '|' if direction=='v' else '--'
```

Comment: quick quick question--the one part that is confusing to me is where you convert the string....just don't understand the subtraction part.  as i think about, it seems that it probably has to do with indexing properties of Python--starting at 0 etc.  Is that it?

Comment: @JohnRogerson Exactly, the subtractions are there to make our coordinates start at 0.

Comment: great thank you.  any tips as to how to updated the board with all of the ships on it, after each ship is placed?  right now it is showing the board with the one ship after every guess

Comment: @JohnRogerson Just remove the first line then. Instead of creating an empty board, pass the board as an argument and let it update the existing one.

Comment: hmm tried that but keep getting a list index out of range--putting at the line with the board [x][y] =

Comment: actually sorry nevermind--realized because i was entering a value that was not on the board.  Thank you for your help!